# Align, multiline, ... more equationsymbols in one line under each other

Tags: equations, align, arrays

I could not find a method to use `\begin{align}` or the other similar commands, s.t. in one line ist not only one = symbol, they are more. And I want arrange the equality sign under each other. No problem with one equality sign, just use a &= b \ c &= d \...
My current solution is to use an array:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, array}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, headsep=0.3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} 
\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle} r >{\displaystyle}l >{\displaystyle}l}
\mathbb{P}(i \leq f_n \leq t+i) & = \int_{i}^{t+i} {\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot e^{-x/n}  \, dx}  & = \Big[- 
e^{-x/n}\Big]_i^{t+i} =  e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \\
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq t) & = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left(e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \right) 
& = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left((1-e^{-t/n})\cdot e^{-i/n}\right)  \\
& = (1-e^{-t/n})\cdot \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} {e^{-i/n}} & = \dfrac{(1-e^{-t/n})}{(1-e^{-1/n})}   \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Btw, `\begin{equation}` should be right here, or? Since there is only one object.

Comment: `aligned` might be an alternative: `\[
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(i \leq f_n \leq t+i) 
  & = \int_{i}^{t+i} {\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot e^{-x/n}  \, dx}  
    && = \Big[- e^{-x/n}\Big]_i^{t+i} =  e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \\
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq t) 
  & = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left(e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \right) 
    && = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left((1-e^{-t/n})\cdot e^{-i/n}\right)  \\
  & = (1-e^{-t/n})\cdot \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} {e^{-i/n}} 
    && = \dfrac{(1-e^{-t/n})}{(1-e^{-1/n})}
\end{aligned}
\]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `alignedat` here I think. Also always use bigl and bigr not big.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, english]{article}
\usepackage[main=english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, mathtools, amsthm, array}
\usepackage[left=3cm, right=3cm, headsep=0.3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\mathbb{P}(i \leq f_n \leq t+i) & = \int_{i}^{t+i} \frac{1}{n}\cdot e^{-x/n}  \, dx  && = \Bigl[- 
e^{-x/n}\Bigr]_i^{t+i} =  e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \\[\jot]
\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}(X_n \leq t) & = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left(e^{-i/n}- e^{-(t+i)/n} \right) 
&& = \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} \left((1-e^{-t/n})\cdot e^{-i/n}\right)  \\[\jot]
& = (1-e^{-t/n})\cdot \sum_{i\in \mathbb{N}_0} {e^{-i/n}} && = \frac{(1-e^{-t/n})}{(1-e^{-1/n})}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```